# Select primary key of user on login. Prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently creating a Profile area so customers can login. During the login process, once the password has been verified, I want to retrieve the users ID (auto increment - unique id) so I can retrieve other data that uses their user ID as a foreign key.

My select statement is as follows:

```
$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT email,password FROM users WHERE email = ?")
```

So if the email matches, the corresponding password is selected. I want to select the users ID along with this, so I can retrieve all of their details (as the ID is used as a foreign key across all tables).

Is it possible to do this using Mysqli Prepared Statements?

Or is there a more feasible way to achieve my goal?

Comment: $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT id, email,password FROM users WHERE email = ?")  why not getting id right away?

Comment: I'm wondering.. what prevents you to do what @MuhammedM. mentioned? Where's the problem?